# Presentation <?> Domain <?> Persistence

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

Ok So I have a

- **PERSISTENCE** layer, which grabs data from Entity Framework and puts it in some classes of its own, "Models", identical to the DB ones.
- **PRESENTATION** layer, an MVC website
- **DOMAIN** layer, which is a project independent to everything. Has some classes (Models) but not exactly as on the DB, has some business logic and so on.

How do I link these 3? (references)

Comment: I wrote an article about this here: http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/05/12/the-n-layer-myth-and-basic-dependency-injection/ The accepted answer reflects the ideas in the article, but there's some more information in the article as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typical *3-tier Application architecture*, you usually make your *Data Access Layer* (Data Persistence Layer if you will) reference your *Domain Layer* - You shouldn't add a reference from your Domain Model to your DAL, that'll create a circular dependency problem.

You then orchestrate the interaction between your Domain and Data Access Layers in your Presentation Layer (MVC App in your case).

In short:

- Your **DAL** should reference your **Domain Layer**.
- Your **Presentation Layer** should reference both your **Domain Layer** and **DAL**

Comment: what about a DDD approach? Should I add more layers?

Comment: Well it depends on how complex your domain logic is. You could add a Service Layer on top of your domain layer to orchestrate the interaction between your Domain and DAL Layer, you could then consume its services from the presentation layer, but for simple applications three layers should be fine, I think.