# Separate Layers in C# for Loose Coupling

Tags: c#, layer

I started to make a banking application, I have a register user form, which the user enters in a firstname, lastname, email, username, password, and verifypassword into their respective text-boxes. Within the UI, I call a static class from the BL, which instantiates an INewUser (interface), and returns it back to me. Then, I set each one of the properties of NewUser (like firstname, lastname, etc.) to the respective textbox.

Once that happens, I call a method from the BL that verifies the users input. Once verified, the INewUser instance gets sent over to the DL, and  inserts the data into the database.

Here is where I am stuck. The interface is being referenced by the UI, BL, and DL. Is this the correct way to do it? Should I nix the INewUser, and just pass the fields directly to the DL (like the firstname, lastname, etc.)?

If this helps, I want the Banking Application to work like this:

1. If user does not exist, user registers a user.
2. User logs in, and has the option to look at their accounts
   (checking, savings, etc.)
3. User can create and view transactions for each one of the account.

Comment: > how to write code and organize a fairly big project "correctly" > winforms > mfw

Comment: Why do you have a separate project for your interfaces? it makes more sense to place them in your BLL. you might want to have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29285410/3052062)

Comment: @chomba Doesn't your answer suggest that having the "API Layer" (layer with INewUser), is the correct way to go?

Comment: @Will >thinking this is a chan >not posting a face >making me comment

Answer (score 0):

The project design really depends on your requirement. No need to forcibly follow a pattern if you doesn't have a purpose. If the database/data-source will not change, you really doesn't require interface for the data transfer.

Check this link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee658109.aspx